# lowest and highest number with for loop

Tags: for-loop, max, min, array-indexing

I am trying to filter an array and find the highest and lowest number (one highest and lowest, if 1 is two times and it's lowest only first one should be taken out from the array, same for the highest) and then with a for loop sum up the rest of the numbers from the array.

First I am trying to find the min and max numbers in the array with Math.min and Math.max and also indexes of them in the array.

I will write the code below it works correctly in the first example but not in the second example.

```
function sumArray(array) {
  let newArr = array;
  let smallest = Math.min(...newArr);
  let realSmall = array.indexOf(smallest);

  let highest = Math.max(...newArr);
  let realHigh = array.indexOf(highest);
  let sumUp = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    if (newArr[i] !== array[realSmall]) {
      if (newArr[i] !== array[realHigh]) {
        sumUp = sumUp + newArr[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return sumUp;
}
```

sumArray([6, 2, 1, 8, 10]);

sumArray([0, 1, 6, 10, 10]);

In the first example, so, I am checking if newArr[i] is different from array[realSmall] - here I am getting the number itself, not the index, and therefore I want to compare newArr[i] to the index itself where this math.min or math.max is located, because in the second example when there is two 10 it returns the wrong result, because array[realHigh]) is 10 in 2 iteration and i want to take out only one lowest, so the result should be 17 not 7, because of that I want to make compare newArr[i] to the index where math.min or max is located and not the result that I am getting from array[realHigh].

I hope i was clear, i already solved this kata but another way, I just want to know how to compare to the index itself, for example newArr[i[ must be different from the index where first ten is located (index of 3 not the result of the array[realHigh] which is 10).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should just check the indices, not the array values. Thus, you could just change `newArr[i] !== array[realSmall]` to `i !== realSmall`, and `newArr[i] !== array[realHigh]` to `i !== realHigh`. Nonetheless, depending on how you wish to consider handling situations where all of the values are the same, you may also want to add some additional checks and handling for that situation.

Comment: Love you : )) 2 days I am working on this kata. Just find the solution with different way, but I knew that was also solution that needed to find for one kata, i used this syntax below, but I just didn't knew how it would work for 2 conditions.

 function removeSmallest(numbers) {

   const smallest = Math.min(...numbers);

   const index = numbers.indexOf(smallest);


   return numbers.filter((_, i) => i !== index);

 }